# Protractor - properly handling the errors...

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, jasmine, protractor

I've tried to put the descriptive error message and exit the test run via fail() function but only with a partial success - it appears that I am doing something wrong... Here is my code:

```
it('set up internal budget', function(done) {
    var acceptBudgetButton = element(by.buttonText('Accept Budget'));
    page.setInternalBudget();  //setting budget values

    browser.wait(function() {
      return browser.isElementPresent(acceptBudgetButton);
    }, 30000, 'Error - Accept Budget button is not visible.');
    acceptBudgetButton.click();
    done();
    done.fail('Unable to setup internal budget. Terminating test run');
  });
```

When "Accept Budget" button is not available I expected 3 things from this script:

1) See "Accept Budget button is not visible" error, followed by wait time out

2) See "Unable to setup internal budget. Terminating test run" error

3) Expect protractor to immediately exist test run, as we got into failure.

In the reality, only first expectation is met. Script keeps on running and I don't even get "Unable to setup internal budget" error... so it looks like my done.fail statement is being ignored.

What should I change to make all of my dreams/expectations come true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nothing would be executed after `done`. What I would do is to define the `browser.wait()`'s success and failure handlers. Something along these lines:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return browser.isElementPresent(acceptBudgetButton);
}, 30000).then(
    function () {
        acceptBudgetButton.click();
        done();
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Error - Accept Budget button is not visible.');
        done.fail('Unable to setup internal budget. Terminating test run');
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your response!!  The only problem I am still having is that script does not exit immediately - it's executes all of the following "its" from the same spec and prints out meaningless messages/errors... I guess, it's impossible to make protractor exit test run with the fail() function. But with your help I got 99% what I was looking for - I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Misha ah, forgot to note that this is the default behavior. Please see if [`jasmine-bail-fast`](https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast) would work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you again, I will try it out.  Just to note, npm install jasmine-bail-fast caused a few pretty suspicious warnings:

-- jasmine-bail-fast@0.0.1  extraneous
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
Note - I am on Windows 7… hopefully this thing will work- I will let you know

Comment: Giving up on jasmine-bail-fast idea for now - it is not supported in Jasmine 2, which is what we have... I also looked into jasmine-fail-fast (wrapper around failing bail-fast) and protractor-fail-fast but there are no clear instructions how to use them (i.e entries in conf file, specs,etc) plus a lot of people complaining that it's now working - so probably not worth time to investigate... I wish Jasmine development had a better clue how to handle this common request (manage when to exit protractor test runs)... oh well!